# Cron Expression for running job every 4 hours starting at 4pm . But should not run between 12am to 7am of the day

Tags: cron

I am trying to create a Cron Expression for running job every 4 hours starting at 4pm, but should not run between 12am to 7am of the day.
So far I tried to do this but it does not work.

```
0 0 16/4 ? 0-2,7-23 * * *
```

Comment: It's cron, not chron.

Comment: Its a typo . I meant Chron. Please provide your answer if you know it .

Comment: No, the term is [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), not Chron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be your cron expression.

```
0 0 16/4,20,8,12 ? * * *
```

Use [this link](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) to get exactly what you are seeking for. It will also helps you with the next execution time.